How can I make php working in background?
Im a sort of beginer and Im asking this question :
Suppose I hage a php file look like this:
<?php
    echo "Your job is accepted\n";

    $f=fopen(some_big_file);
    // Do intensive work that takes 5 seconds
    fclose(some_big_file);
?>

The only thing I want the user to see is the first message but in this case it takes 5 seconds before seeing the message.
Is there something I can add (like 'return') to have the php script continue the heavy job in backgroud (I mean after the echoed message) so the time to get the echo would not depend of the heavy work?
Hope I'm clear but not sure;-)
Thanks
I tried to remove the heavy work and the message is echoed instantly

Sorry for bad quotes

You could send Your job is accepted client side and make ajax request that processes the request, or create a processor that runs server side on CRON for these. Depends what the PHP process is doing, does user need data in browser or it gets emailed to them?

This sort of process is generally done via a job queue, like Laravel Queues. The first script submits a request to the queue and then immediately exits. Then you'd have one or more job runners always going in the background, looking for new jobs to do.

This depends heavily on the details, so your experience may differ.
Since your PHP script is intended for the web and the message should be seen by the user in the browser, PHP can send the text immediately by flushing it. The PHP function is flush(). As the manual explains, you cannot use it to control buffering of either the web server or the browser.
However, based on the description in your question, it might already be sufficient.
If you are working in FCGI, there is also the function fastcgi_finish_request(). It finishes the request and the rest of the PHP script then runs in the "background". This means that it can no longer send any output to the browser (user), but it continues to run.
This could also be sufficient according to the description in your question.
For both functions, there is already a lot of information in the PHP manual online about the relevant parts (output buffering, session handling, headers, ...) and often you want to keep things simple, so you can find collected wisdom there.
As mentioned in the comments, a work queue with PHP client libraries can prove very effective. You can find one in beanstalkd.
IMHO, a queue can practically add more overhead than gain for five seconds of work, especially for small projects, but as written, it depends on the project and your mileage may vary.
